# Универсальный метод на пустое значение в JS

Tags: javascript

На вход в функцию поступает значение всех типов Boolean, Object, String, Symbol. (Array тоже входит в подмножество Object)

Нужен метод проверки, который определит, пустое ли это значение или нет. Есть какие нибудь готовые функции или библиотеки, которые решают мою проблему?

Пример:

```
isEmpty([]) === true
```

Но

```
isEmpty(0) !== true
```

Так что проверки типа `!!value` не прокатят.

Comment: Ну для массива, строки, объекта понятно, а для Boolean и числа пустое - это что?

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEmpty